# Active Directory Password Reset Enforce Password History

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have a requirement that allows a user to reset their password to what they would like. However, when doing it through Powershell `Set-ADAccountPassword` function and using the reset parameter, it doesn't enforce the password history. So using the function would allow the user to reset it to a previous password. Am I missing something here or is there a way I can enforce the password history during a reset?

Comment: The way I use this to reset passwords is I don't let the user pick the password. The script generates a random password and sets it to that. Then the user can log on temporarily with the reset password and change it once the minimum password age as expired.

Comment: That’s exactly how we have it configured today. But the client I’m working with doesn’t like that solution  was wondering if there was something I was missing with this power shell command that enforced the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behavior for -Reset.

First reset the password to a random value using parameters -NewPassword and -Reset.

Then run Set-ADAccountPassword again and specify -OldPassword [the random password] -NewPassword [the new password they entered], without the -Reset parameter. That will enforce the password age, history, complexity, and length.

Comment: This is a good solution and one I didn't really think of. One question I have is if the domain has a minimum of 1 day password age, will this still work? Or will there still need to be a wait period?

Comment: @BrandonWilson: it will enforce all the rules, including age.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to create some sort of self-service password reset facility? Don't. I would place this in the same category of [don't write your own cryptography, because you WILL get it wrong](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own).

`Set-ADAccountPassword` is the equivalent of an administrator doing a password reset through Active Directory Users and Computers.

There are plenty of inexpensive products that do this already, written by people smarter than you or I. I strongly urge you to evaluate one of those rather than potentially creating a security hole in your network.

Comment: I understand there are products out there and we are using one right now, but it is being retired for other reasons beyond my control. One software we have uses this Powershell command to reset the password and therefore doesn't enforce the history. We can modify this and I was wondering if there is a way to do it. The current software we have allows the user to reset their password and enforces history.